# Please stop forcing the user out of edit mode when another user makes an edit

Tags: feature-request, edits

I've noticed in the last week or so that the UI method of updating when an edit is made has changed. Perviously you would see a yellow bar above the question or answer saying that an edit had been made and to click the bar to view it. This system worked well.

It seems an update to this has been made which now instantly updates the Q/A on screen as soon as the other user finished their edit. This too works well, mostly.

The issue is that when you are in edit mode of the content your edits will be instantly discarded and you will be returned back to the normal view of the question *as soon as the other user finishes their edit*.

I have lost track of the number of times in the last few days I lost formatting or grammatical edits because someone decided to fix a typo, or remove a tag.

Please change the behaviour so that the edits are only instantly applied if you are *not* in edit mode.

Comment: @Gothdo thanks. I did search but nothing came up